# Incorrect syntax near 'userId' on search query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a search query which is throwing this error `Incorrect syntax near 'userId'` and I have no idea on why and how can I solve it. It is now affecting other

my sql query

```
oCommand = new SqlCommand(@"Select us.sFieldValue5, u.sUserName, d.sName, TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO.sFieldValue2, u.nUserIdn
From TB_USER u(nolock)
left join [TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO] us(nolock) on us.nUserIdn = u.nUserIdn
left join TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO on  u.nUserIdn = TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO.nUserIdn
left join TB_USER_DEPT d(nolock) on d.nDepartmentIdn = u.nDepartmentIdn
where (u.sUserName like '%" + txtUsername.Text + @"%' or '" + txtUsername.Text + @"' = '')
and (us.sFieldValue5 like '%" + txtUserID.Text + @"%' or '" + txtUserID.Text + @"' = '')
and (d.sDepartment like '%" + sDepartment + @"%' or '" + sDepartment + @"' = '--Select Department--')
and (u.nUserIdn = " + userId + @" or " + txtusersID.Text + @" = 0)", oConnection);
```

Comment: Please use parameterised queries to avoid building up queries like this. It makes your code safer and easier to read.

Comment: What variable type is userId in the last line?

Comment: string builder , formatter , parameterised queries , please make use of this dear , makes your code mature...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with a parameterized query. What you are doing is incredibly dangerous and won't work at all if someone includes a single quote in a text box. (e.g. txtUserID.Text = "I'm going to crash now")

```
oCommand = new SqlCommand(@"Select us.sFieldValue5, u.sUserName, d.sName, TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO.sFieldValue2, u.nUserIdn
            From TB_USER u(nolock)
            left join [TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO] us(nolock) on us.nUserIdn = u.nUserIdn
            left join TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO on  u.nUserIdn = TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO.nUserIdn
            left join TB_USER_DEPT d(nolock) on d.nDepartmentIdn = u.nDepartmentIdn
            where (u.sUserName like ('%' + @UserName + '%') or @UserName = '')
            and (us.sFieldValue5 like ('%' + @UserId + '%') or @UserId = '')
            and (d.sDepartment like ('%' + @Department + '%') or @Department = '--Select Department--')
            and (u.nUserIdn = @UserId or @UserId2 = 0)", oConnection);    

oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUsername.Text)
//etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the **UserID** in the last line of the code, you need to specify the column name before the **OR** operator.

Check the below corrected code:

```
oCommand = new SqlCommand(@"Select us.sFieldValue5, u.sUserName, d.sName, TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO.sFieldValue2, u.nUserIdn
                From TB_USER u(nolock)
                left join [TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO] us(nolock) on us.nUserIdn = u.nUserIdn
                left join TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO on  u.nUserIdn = TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO.nUserIdn
                left join TB_USER_DEPT d(nolock) on d.nDepartmentIdn = u.nDepartmentIdn
                where (u.sUserName like '%" + txtUsername.Text + @"%' or '" + txtUsername.Text + @"' = '')
                and (us.sFieldValue5 like '%" + txtUserID.Text + @"%' or '" + txtUserID.Text + @"' = '')
                and (d.sDepartment like '%" + sDepartment + @"%' or '" + sDepartment + @"' = '--Select Department--')
                and (u.nUserIdn = " + userId + @" or u.nUserIdn = " + txtusersID.Text + @")", oConnection);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give the following syntax when running as a string: `(u.nUserIdn = SOMETHING or u.nUserIdn = SOMETHING = 0)`